# Image in an NSTabViewItem not showing up

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Xcode interface builder allows me to set an image for an `NSTabViewItem`. However, the image is not showing up when the app is running. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same problem. It is the bug in the system. Some images dont show up at all.
I then used [object setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSActionTemplate]];